# Can you remove wordpress post tags with js/php after certain date (ACF date time picker)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, tags

So my website lists upcoming film screenings in my area.

I'm using the ACF date time picker to only show posts/film screenings that are in the future in the wordpress loop.

I have tags filtering the results dynamically using ajax (thanks to https://www.bobz.co/ajax-filter-posts-tag/) except there are tags that aren't relevant to the results because they belong to posts that are older than the current date (past screenings).

*For example on the website, the 'animated film festival' is still coming up with the other tags.

I don't know if it's possible to delete a posts tags with PHP (within the post template while it loops through other posts) - and to delete the posts tags if the ACF date time field for that post is older than the current date.

I haven't found much luck googling this and I am a bit of a noob so...

This is my site: http://pigcine.pamrosel.com/
This is what I'm doing in my functions.php file at the moment:

```
// Get all tags and display
function tags_filter() {
    $tax = 'post_tag';
    $terms = get_terms( $tax );
    $count = count( $terms );

    if ( $count > 0 ): ?>
        <div class="post-tags">
        <?php
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $tax );
            echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter"         title="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
        } ?>       
        </div>
    <?php endif; }

// Script for getting posts
function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

// Verify nonce
if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
die('Permission denied');

$taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];

// WP Query
$args = array(
'tag' => $taxonomy,
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key'  => 'datetime',
        'orderby'    => array(
        'datetime' => 'ASC'
        ),
);

// If taxonomy is not set, remove key from array and get all posts
if( !$taxonomy ) {
unset( $args['tag'] );
}

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query>the_post(); 
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+9 hours'));
$event_date = get_field('datetime');
if (strtotime($today) <= strtotime($event_date)) {
?>

<div class="sl">

<div class="sl_closed">

    <div class="col-2-8"><div class="modulepad">
     <p><?php the_field('datetime'); ?></p>
    </div></div>

    <div class="col-3-8"><div class="modulepad">
     <p><?php the_title(); ?><br>
     <?php $wpmovieinput = get_field('movie_title'); $movie = imdb_connector_get_movie($wpmovieinput); echo implode(", ", $movie["directors"]); ?>
     </p>
    </div></div>

    <div class="col-3-8"><div class="modulepad">
     <p><?php the_field('location_name'); ?><br>
     <?php $wpmovieinput = get_field('movie_title'); $movie = imdb_connector_get_movie($wpmovieinput); echo implode(", ", $movie["countries"]) . " "; echo $movie["released"] . " "; echo implode(", ", $movie["runtime"]); ?>
     </p>
    </div></div>

</div><!--SL_CLOSED-->


<?php } endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
 <h2>No posts found</h2>
<?php endif;

die();
} 
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```